# How Do I Have My XPS Driver (built with Microsoft's XPSDrvrSmpl) Remove Jobs From Its Queue on Windows 7 x64?

Tags: c++, windows-7-x64, xps

**Summary:**

We've built an XPS driver using Microsoft's XPS Driver Sample template (source: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/print/XPSDrvSmpl). Everything works fine for our clients using Windows 10. Unfortunately, jobs are left in the queue after printing completes with the status: "Document Seuqnce 1 - Fixed Document - Fixed Page 1" For users on Windows 7. Although it's possible to support 32-bit, we officially only support 64-bit for this driver.

[image]

**Question:**

As the title states, how do I modify my code to be compatible with Windows 7? If there's no such solution, then is there an update or patch for Windows 7 where XPS functions the same way as on Windows 10?

**Additional Information:**

- I've tried [this update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2028551/an-update-is-available-that-contains-improvements-to-xps-in-windows-7)
- I've also noticed similar issues people face on Pre-Vista OSes, where they modified their .inf file sections `[INSTALL_XDSMPL_FILTERS_PRE_VISTA]` and `[INSTALL_XDSMPL_FILTERS_VISTA]` respectively as suggested [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/810b31f6-db5c-4344-b9a6-e042034f19b9/xpsdrvsmp-sample-from-the-wdk-6001?forum=wpf)